# How to set an expiration date on a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with this code:

```
@ECHO off
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxifier\Proxifier.exe"
timeout /t 5 >NUL
START "" "E:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe"
timeout /t 65 >NUL
Taskkill /IM "Proxifier.exe" /F
Exit
```

I want to set an expiration date for this batch file.

For example: The programs wont run on 11/30/2018

How do I set an expiration date on this code?

Comment: What does the expiry date have to do with the code you have posted? What do you mean by expiry date? How is the batch file being invoked? What have you tried? Do you know how this site works? Have you taken the [tour]? Do you know [ask]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Example dates are used in the `IF` conditions in a format `YYYYMMDD` (you can set your own values):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /value') do for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"

set "LocalDateTime=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%"

::echo %LocalDateTime%

:: EXPIRATION DATE ::
set "EXP_DATE=20181130"
:::::::::::::::::::::


if %LocalDateTime% GTR %EXP_DATE% (
    echo this wont work anymore
    exit /b 
)


START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxifier\Proxifier.exe"
timeout /t 5 >NUL
START "" "E:\Program Files (x86)\Epic 
Games\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe"
timeout /t 65 >NUL
Taskkill /IM "Proxifier.exe" /F
Exit
```

Comment: Thanks For Helping , And Working Fine. Just When Expired Date The Batch File Not Opening the CMD , Right?

Comment: @DariushGavari - it will be closed pretty fast. You can set `pause` on the line above the `exit /b` if you want the users to see your message.

Comment: I have one problem. when i change exit to pause , when say please press any key to continue, the programs will run with this date 20181030 -- but when that code with exit /b works fine

Comment: @DariushGavari try to set `pause` on the line ABOVE the `exit`. you can keep the both commands.

Comment: @DariushGavari, as the comment says, put it above the line.  I am not sure how why you think changing it would make it work the same.  This tells me you are not even bothering to understand what each command does.

Comment: Thanks, I Add Pause /b Command above exit /b and now fix and works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```bat
@echo off

set "expirationDate=30112018"
call:check_expire
if %var_return% EQU 0 (goto main_code) else (exit /b)
goto main_code

:main_code
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proxifier\Proxifier.exe"
timeout /t 5 >NUL
START "" "E:\Program Files (x86)\EpicGames\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe"
timeout /t 65 >NUL
Taskkill /IM "Proxifier.exe" /F
pause
exit /b 0

:check_expire
for %%a in (%date%) do set dt=%%a
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %dt%') do (
if "%expirationDate%" LEQ "%%a%%b%%c" (set "var_return=1") else (set "var_return=0")
)
```

Please check also https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/14804d47-5887-4119-a9fd-167d2a14df53/set-a-batch-file-expiration-date?forum=ITCG

Hope this helps!